# Linear Programming #3

Tags: linear-programming

A small tailors’ company wants to use at least 130 yards of fabric to sew evening skirts and dresses. A dress requires 4 yards of fabric and the production of a skirt will need 3 yards. Research shows that they will be able to sell at most three times as many skirts as dresses . A dress will take 10 hours to produce and a skirt will take 1 hour. They can assign to this work no more than 286 hours. Each dress will sell for 540,andeachskirtwillsellfor
540
a
n
d
e
a
c
h
s
k
i
r
t
w
i
l
l
s
e
l
l
f
o
r
180. How many skirts should they sew to maximize the profit?

Click this - https://www.desmos.com/calculator/0a8b743iyi

It will show the equations I made with it graphed. I need help here. What should I do now?

Also - C(x,y) = 540x+180y (right)?

For the vertices I got - (26,8.667),(27.667,9.226),(0,43.333)and (0,286)

Do I know need to plug these into the C(x,y)...?
Once I find the largest, some of the points have fractions. Do i round up???

Comment: If you round up, you'll no longer be within the constraints.

Comment: Honestly, I do these every year with my students and can't recall a time when fractions came into play. I would round down, then calculate the C value of each rounded point.

Comment: could u pls do it for me? sorry

Comment: No. You can remove all the numbers after the decimal places on your own! Then calculate C for each point and compare.

Comment: I got that (27,9) would work but it says 9 is not correct???

Answer (score 0):

Solve the problem getting real numbers for the number of skirts and dresses. Let's say the optimal solution says "35 4/9ths dresses". That's of course not possible. The number of dresses is either ≤ 35 or ≥ 36, not in between.

So you duplicate your problem, once adding the inequality "dresses ≤ 35" and once adding the inequality "dresses ≥ 36". Solve both, and pick the solution that is better. Each solution might have a non-integer value for the number of skirts. In that case you need to do the same again.

Comment: What do u mean by solve and pick the one that is better?? could u give me  what i should do in with real vertices in the problem?

Comment: read what i said above

Answer (score 0):

You implemented the constraint on the number of skirts and dresses incorrectly.

The number of skirts is at most 3 times the number of dresses. So if you can't make 286 skirts and 0 dresses since 286 is not less than 3*0.

Let dresses be x and skirts y, then if you make 20 dresses, you make at most 60 skirts

The correct constraint is y<=3x.

Then your vertices are (10,30), (22,66), and (28,6). You can take it from there.